# Inconsistant Indexing while having manytomany relationship through join-table in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, many-to-many, hibernate-search, join

I have indexing problem with lucene through hibernate search:

Product Domain:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="T_PRD")
    @Indexed
    public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_TMPL_ATTR_VALUE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EntityId", unique=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AttrId", unique=false) }, uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EntityId","AttrId"}))
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix="prd.ca.")
    private Set<TemplateAttribute> customTemplateAttributes;
}
```

TemplateAttribute Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TMPL_ATTRS")
public class TemplateAttribute implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "templateAttribute")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<TemplateAttributeValue> templateAttrValues = new HashSet<TemplateAttributeValue>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_TMPL_ATTR_VALUE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AttrId", unique=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EntityId", unique=false)}, uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EntityId","AttrId"}))


    @ContainedIn
    private Set<Product> product;

@Column(name = "DefaultValue")
private String defaultValue;

}
```

TemplateAttributeValue Domain (**Bridge table**, which have **attrValue** field to contain product specific value):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TMPL_ATTR_VALUE")
public class TemplateAttributeValue implements java.io.Serializable {

    @DocumentId(name="id")
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
    @AttributeOverride(name = "entityId", column = @Column(name = "EntityId", nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "attrId", column = @Column(name = "AttrId", nullable = false)) })
    @FieldBridge(impl = TemplateAttributeCompositeKeyBridge.class)
    public TemplateAttributeValueId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AttrId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ContainedIn
    public TemplateAttribute getTemplateAttribute() {
        return this.templateAttribute;
    }

    @Column(name = "AttrValue")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    public String getAttrValue() {
        return this.attrValue==null?"":this.attrValue;
    }
}
```

I called doIndex methos as below:

```
private void doIndex() throws InterruptedException {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.enableFilter("onlyProductTemplate");
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

    fullTextSession.close();
}
```

So let's assume below data for example:

```
Product:

ID | Name
----------
 1 | Prd1
 2 | Prd2
 3 | Prd3

Template Attribute:

AttrId | DefaultValue
---------------------
1 | Template1
2 | Template2


Template Attribute Value:

AttrId | EntityId | AttrValue
-----------------------------
1 | 1 | Template1
2 | 1 | Template2_modified
1 | 2 | Template1Updated
1 | 2 | Template2
1 | 3 | Template1
2 | 3 | Template2_newValue
```

So when i create index for Product Entity, each product generate indexe **all AttrValue** defined in **Template Attribute Value**.

Due to this when seaching for specific product have some matching any template attribute value, it returns all product in list.

So how to resolve this problem in hibernate search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution through implementing `StringBridge` as below:

```
    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object value) {
        if(value != null) {
            String templateType = null;  
            if(value instanceof Set) {
                StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
                Set<TemplateAttribute> setOfTempAttr = (Set<TemplateAttribute>) value;
                for(TemplateAttribute tempValue : setOfTempAttr) {
                    int productID = tempValue.getProduct().getProductId();
                    Set<TemplateAttributeValue> setOfTempAttrValues = tempValue.getTemplateAttrValues();

                    for (TemplateAttributeValue taValue : setOfTempAttrValues) {
                        int entityID = taValue.getId().getEntityId();
                        if(entityID == productID) {
                            strBuild.append(" " + taValue.getAttrValue());
                        }

                    }
                }
                return strBuild.toString();
            } else if(value instanceof String) {
                templateType = (String) value;
            }
            return templateType;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Means we need **to ignore that attrValue(s) to be indexed for the product to which they don't belongs**. one  more changes remove @indexedEmbedded/@ContainedIn annotation and define like below:

```
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    @FieldBridge(impl = TemplateAttributeValueProductFieldBridge.class)
 private Set<TemplateAttribute> customTemplateAttributes;
```